# Javascript: prototype of Number

Tags: javascript, prototype, numbers

```
var x= 1;  
Number.prototype.test = function () { return this };  
x.test() === x.test() // false
```

Why does the `===` test return false?

Comment: Try outputting (e.g. through console.log or alert, don't know your context) the value it returns. Yeah I don't know how that would help, but it's something to start with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `this` will be a Number object, not the original primitive number value, and comparing two equally created objects will always return false:

```
{"test":"Hello"} === {"test":"Hello"} // false

// Check the typeof your vars
var x= 1;  
Number.prototype.test = function () { return this };  
x.test() === x.test() // false 
alert("x is a "+typeof(x)+", x.test() is an "+typeof(x.test()));
```

If you're looking for a fix, cast `this` to a number

```
var x= 1;  
Number.prototype.test = function () { return +this };  
x.test() === x.test() // TRUE!
alert("x is a "+typeof(x)+", x.test() is also a "+typeof(x.test()));
```

Comment: @eugene: good spot on the syntax errors (the missed closing parenthesis in each code block). Thanks for the edit :)

Comment: Comparing objects always returns false? Now that's ugly... How to check if two objects are the same one then?

Comment: @Bart: good spot, I meant comparing to equally created objects will return false.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call `.test()` a new instance of Number is created, it is much expected behavior, every boxing solution works this way. You can try the same thing in C# and Java and will get absolutely the same result. (Well, Java have pool of Integer objects for small numbers, so you won't get absolutely the same results)

Answer (score 0):

While we are checking the `===` operator , it will check same type , object .

Here , the problem may be because of different object creation .